# WCF WebHttpBinding Testing Tool

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client, webhttpbinding, wcf-rest

I'm developing WCF RESTful Services and looking for a testing tool/invoker for calling these services without writing client code. Can anybody refer me to a tool for invoking RESTful services especially services using the WCF WebHttpBinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOA Cleaner has a special mode for testing WebHttpBinding, SOA Cleaner can also test soap, rest and WCF webservices.
can be downloaded at: http://xyrow.com.
good luck.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful. I've completely resolved my problem by using SOA Cleaner. It's a very pretty and powerful tool.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Pylot in the past for doing some automated testing of restful services:

http://www.pylot.org/

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this with restful web services but you can use the WCFTestClient.exe tool that comes with the .NET SDK.  my version is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE

Comment: I thik you are mistaken, wcftestclient doesn't support webhttpbinding. I tried it several times, Take a look at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/deabd25b-a219-4e95-9826-d40dc2f75543/.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and a related [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414875/best-tool-framework-for-testing-a-restful-service).